# How to resolve IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I'm new to python and I have a csv file which contains 35 columns. To print the last column of each i'm executing the script below:

````
import csv

filename = '/home/cloudera/PMGE/Bfr.csv'
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in datareader:
        print(row[34])
```
It prints the expected result but at the end i have this error:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "barplot.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(row[34])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone help me to understand this?
````

Comment: Try `print(len(row))` before `print(row[34])`. I’ll wager that one of your rows does not have enough columns.

Comment: @SethMMorton Thank you. Indeed there were two lines of one column each which had been added when I imported my csv file.

Comment: When something unexpected happens, *always* check that your assumptions are correct before anything else. In this case the assumption was on the row length. This will help you solve 90% of all your errors in the future.